# Javascript: безопасны ли висячие запятые?

Tags: javascript

Один мой коллега очень любит при определении константных Javascript-объектов оставлять висячие запятые:

```
var myObj = {
    prop1: 'smth',
    prop2: 'smthElse', // <--- Висячая запятая!
}
```

Мотивирует он это тем, что при исправлении такого объекта программист получит более релевантный вывод в диффе (1 строчку вместо двух).

Мне такой стиль очень не нравится, но по причинам также чисто эстетическим:
1. JSLint на такое ругается
2. Неподдержка в старых IE (8-). Но под них мы все равно не пишем.

Стандарт вообще говоря такое разрешает.

Внимание, вопрос: известны ли вам еще причины по которым висячие запятые стоит/не стоит использовать? Например положительное/отрицательное влияние на сборщики-оптимизаторы или что-нибудь в этом духе

Comment: В качестве плюса - можно безболезненно добавлять/удалять новые поля объекта без необходимости следить за запятой.

Comment: Ещё удобно для автоматической генерации кода, не нужно обрабатывать отдельно последнюю строку.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну первое так себе аргумент, любой валидатор будет гореть на это куда сильнее чем на висячую запятую.

Comment: Про автогенерацию кода не думал, действительно аргумент (не наш кейс впрочем)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, если нормально генерировать автоматически последнюю строку и не надо обрабатывать: в большинстве случаев есть функции объединяющие массив в строку.

Comment: Поддерживаю вашего коллегу в плане удобства чтения diffa. Кроме того, с висячими запятыми blame сразу находит оригинальную ревизию, а не ту, в которой запятую дописали.

Comment: @Grundy в простых случаях да, но что если например комментарий стоит после запятой, как в примере ru_volt

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну и что? :-)

Comment: @Grundy наверное я неправильно понял, думал вы предлагаете делать что-то вроде `.join(',\n')` для массива строк.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, да я примерно это и имел ввиду, как простой случай

Comment: @Grundy в случае с комментарием придется отдельно обрабатывать последнюю строку (исключить запятую), либо просто оставлять её (обычная склейка джойном не поможет в такой ситуации).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, на самом деле все зависит от метода генерации, можно обрабатывать первую строку например, кроме того, ящитаю, в сгенерированном коде комментарии не нужны

Comment: @Grundy т.е. логика генератора так или иначе усложняется для варианта без последней запятой. На счет ненужности комментариев не соглашусь, более того, на мой взгляд сгенерированный код также должен быть правильно отформатирован для удобства чтения.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, генератор сам по себе довольно сложная штука, кроме того комментарии не относятся к форматированию, следовательно при отсутствии комментариев вполне хватит `.join(',\n')`  и результат будет тем же без дополнительных затрат, ну и в крайнем случае проверка одного условия не так уж и сильно усложнит код одного простого цикла

Comment: @PashaPash, а чтобы объединить удобство чтения diff-а с синтаксисом (произвольного) языка программирования, можно запятую ставить в начале строки с очередным элементом списка (кроме первой такой строки, разумеется).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Строго говоря: [стандарт **не** запрещает использование висячих запятых в инициализаторе объекта](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer)

```
ObjectLiteral[Yield] :  
    { }
    { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] }
    { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] , }
```

Таким образом ставить или не ставить запятую целиком на совести разработчика.

В итоге, все решается договоренностью внутри группы разработчиков, чтобы код был однообразным.

Так как это допустимый вариант инициализации - никаких влияний на оптимизацию(минимизацию) оказываться не должно, но зависит от реализации оптимизатора/минификатора.

Что касается проверяльщиков: все зависит от правил, которые довольно гибко могут настраиваться.

---

#### UPD: июль 2017

Добавлю, что, на июль 2017 года, один из самых популярных стайлгайдов - стайлгайд от airbnb не просто не запрещает висячие запятые, [**а требует их**](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#commas--dangling).

Comment: Так как это допустимый вариант инициализации - никаких влияний на оптимизацию(минимизацию) оказываться не должно. - Утверждение представляется мне неверным.

Comment: А то что стандарт не запрещает да и правила можно настроить, это итак понятно)

Comment: @ru_volt, _Утверждение представляется мне неверным_ - почему же? там кстати приписка есть, что может зависеть от реализации :) кроме того более чем уверен, что если не все, то большинство минификаторов просто отбросят данную запятую, как не важную часть

Comment: Раз стандарт такую штуку разрешает, то оптимизаторы-минификаторы должны ее прожевать, с этим я согласен. Но при этом может случиться такое что прожевывать они могут ее с соверешенно разным трудом. Это раз.

Comment: @ru_volt, ну это будет уже проблема конкретного оптимизатора/минификатора

Comment: Для минификаторов же существуют небезопасные режимы. Это два.

Comment: Ну ладно, я понял, ваш ответ на мой вопрос "мне о различиях неизвестно" =)

Comment: @ru_volt _Для минификаторов же существуют небезопасные режимы. Это два._ - в данном случае без разницы, так как запятая находится _внутри_ инициализатора, и не влияет ни на порядок свойств, ни на свойства объявленного объекта

Comment: @ru_volt, если ваш оптимизатор не в состоянии оптимизировать код, валидный по стандарту -- грош ему цена и место в помойке. В экосистеме JS существует достаточно инструментов работающих так, как следует

Comment: Я и спрашиваю, не известно ли о наличии проблем у каких-либо известных инструментов с такими конструкциями. Мой тезис "я вполне допускаю что некоторые распространенные инструменты могут здесь лажать, не слышали ли Вы о таком?". Я не говорю что они _должны_ лажать.